Using long-run propensities to compare magnitude of association among independent variables
Is it feasible to add up all significant lags of respective independent variables (disregarding insignificant ones) in order to compare the strength or magnitude of their respective association with the dependent variable?
I've specified an ARDL model of quarterly time series data, all first differences, regressing the change in commodity futures price on the change in several independent variables representing supply and demand conditions, respectively. Since the agricultural commodity in question has a crop cycle of one year, 4 lags of all variables were included and subsequently restricted, eliminating only the furthest lag when insignificant. As such, there are insignificant lags of independent variables in the model when a further lag is significant.
Just for context, the purpose of the study is not to forecast prices, but understand the relationship between price movements and changes in fundamental factors relevant to the underlying commodity, and fundamentals relevant to another (non-tenderable) commodity in order to gauge whether the price has been distorted by irrelevant information.
For example, I want to say that the association between price and relevant supply is indicated by the sum of beta coefficients for all significant lags of the relevant supply variable (its LRP); the association between price and irrelevant supply is the LRP of the irrelevant supply variable.
Can it be concluded that the irrelevant supply LRP is the magnitude of price distortion? Can I compare the relevant vs. irrelevant LRP's to understand which has the greater association with price movements?
